# How to fix ERROR TypeError: "_co.news is undefined"?

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to get some data from the backend to display it on the component.
Everything works, but somehow I'm getting this error:  ERROR TypeError: "_co.news is undefined".
Does someone had a simular issue?

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  isMobileResolution: boolean;

  news: News[] = [];

  constructor(private newsService: NewsService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.readNews();
  }

  readNews(){
    this.newsService.readNews().subscribe((news: News[])=>{
      this.news = news;
    })
  }

}
```

```html
<container *ngIf="!isMobileResolution">
  <news-card 
    [title]="news[0].title"
    [date]="news[0].date"
    [preview]="news[0].preview">
  </news-card>
  <div id="news-area">
    <news-card
      id="left"
      [lessText]="true"
      [title]="news[1].title"
      [date]="news[1].date"
      [preview]="news[1].preview">
    </news-card>
    <news-card
      id="right"
      [lessText]="true"
      [title]="news[2].title"
      [date]="news[2].date"
      [preview]="news[2].preview">
    </news-card>
  </div>
</container>
```

Comment: Your service function must be returning `undefined`. Can't say more without seeing that.

Comment: Have you checked the interface News has all these keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can change your ngIf:

```
<container *ngIf="!isMobileResolution && news?.length >= 3">
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked! Could you explain me why I have to check this?

Comment: because your news arrive after component being rendered. It means when angular tries to render the view, `news` objects is still undefined. hence you get `undefined` exception. Also, google about async pipe. It's better to use that one instead of manual subscription

Comment: @Vitaly. I had a similar issue. I used your solution and it worked. But there are doubts in my head. 1) Will it pass unit test cases. 2) Is it among the best practices. My code reviewer may have objections on this.

Comment: @Vitaly. My scrum master will definitely ask these cross questions. Please help.